# IMCE module to load images from local hard disk

Tags: drupal

I'm using Drupal as my content-management system. I installed the [IMCE](http://drupal.org/project/imce) module to include images on my site. This works fine, but I can only choose the images from the server, which means I have to copy them on the server and can then choose them. But I would like to choose them from my local hard drive.
Does anyone know if it is possible to do that with that module, or do I need another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. IMCE provides an upload button (See [linked image](http://drupal.cocomore.com/system/files/blog_photos/awesome_drupal_7_wysiwyg/imce_window_upload_button.png), top left. I tried to embed it in my post, but the system here won't allow me to add images yet).

But by default, only User-1 has access to it and you'll have to create and associate profiles with roles to allow actions such as uploading of files. If you haven't done so, this is configured on:
`admin/settings/imce` (Drupal 6), or
`admin/config/media/imce` (Drupal 7)
So if you aren't logged in as User-1 and don't see the upload button, it's likely a configuration step you are missing.

I wrote an article recently which goes pretty in-depth about use of the IMCE module and gets into configuration. It also covers the workflow for adding images to WYSIWYG content editors, and is written with Drupal 7 in mind, but the IMCE-relevant stuff is mostly the same between Drupal 6 and 7. You may also want to use the IMCE_Mkdir module, which allows users with appropriate permission (added to the IMCE configuration for each profile) to create new sub-directories, which can help keep your images or other files better organized.

You can read my relevant article on the Cocomore Drupal blog: [Configuring and adding images to Drupal 7 content with Wysiwyg, IMCE and Lightbox2](http://drupal.cocomore.com/blog/configuring-and-adding-images-drupal-7-content-wysiwyg-imce-and-lightbox)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Click the 'upload' button in IMCE...that will allow you to upload images to the server using the UI, then you can choose them. There's no other way of doing this as obviously it's a website...if you want files from your local machine on the server you'll have to transfer them there. This is what IMCE's 'upload' button is for.

You might also want to check out the [IMCE WYSIWYG Bridge module](http://drupal.org/project/imce_wysiwyg) if you're using WYSIWYG, it provides a nice easy way to upload images into WYSIWYG if you're using that module.

Answer (score 0):

Just a tip that always bother using drupal. If you don't see some config options after installing a new module (it was my case for this threat), you must clean caches , in D7 /admin/config/development/performance